# change date format från 2019-02-04 to 04 feb

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have a python script for a e-paper frame. I'd like to change the date from "2019-02-04" to "04 feb" instead. I've been tweaking the code for hours now, and I can't get it to work.

The code looks like this:

```
# Calendar strings to be displayed
day_str = time.strftime("%A")
day_number = time.strftime("%d")
month_str = time.strftime("%B") + ' ' + time.strftime("%Y")
month_cal = str(calendar.month(int(time.strftime("%Y")), int(time.strftime("%m"))))
month_cal = month_cal.split("\n",1)[1];
update_moment = time.strftime("%H") + ':' + time.strftime("%M")
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess its the 5th row of code that should be altered.
month_cal = str(calendar.month(int(time.strftime("%Y")), int(time.strftime("%m"))))

I tried to change the Y and m to m and b, but with no luck at all. I'm sorry, but I don't know where to insert the code that you applied :/

Answer (score 1):

```
d = '2019-02-04'
datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%d %b')
```

**Output**

```
'04 Feb'
```

Comment: Thanks alot iamklaus! I'll try that.

Comment: Jeez... I got it all wrong. The code above got nothing to do with it. Here it is...

current_date = int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%j')) + (int(time.strftime("%Y")) * 365)
        if 'due' in my_task:
            due_date = int(datetime.date(int(str(my_task['due']['date']).split('-')[0]), int(str(my_task['due']['date']).split('-')[1]), int(str(my_task['due']['date']).split('-')[2])).strftime('%j')) + (int(str(my_task['due']['date']).split('-')[0]) * 365)
        else:
            due_date = -1